# get coordinates of a patch in a raster map (raster package in R)

Tags: r, coordinates, raster

I have a raster map with many patches (clumps of continguous cells with the same value). What I need to do is to obtain the coordinates of the center (or close to the center) of each patch.
I am very unexperienced with raster package but it seems I can get coordinates only if I know the position of the cells in the map. Is there any way to get coordinates giving a value of the cells instead? Thank you

Comment: How did you create you create/import your raster? I would be simpler to help you if you showed a sample of your data, the code you used to create your raster and/or what you tried.

Comment: See `?click` and possibly also `?zoom`.

Comment: As an alternative, you might want to use ImageJ, which has clump/spot-finding tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the mean of the coordinates of each patch:

```
# some dummy data
m <- matrix(c(
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,
    0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), nrow=20, byrow=T)

# create a raster
r <- raster(m)

# convert raster to points
p <- data.frame(rasterToPoints(r))

# filter out packground
p <- p[p$layer > 0,]

# for each patch calc mean coordinates
sapply(split(p[, c("x", "y")], p$layer), colMeans)
```

Answer (score 5):

If by patch you mean clumps, Raster package allows you to find , and isolate, clumps. Taking the `clump()` raster package example, and extending it:

```
library(raster)
library(igraph)
detach("package:coin", unload=TRUE)
r <- raster(ncols=12, nrows=12)
set.seed(0)
r[] <- round(runif(ncell(r))*0.7 )
rc <- clump(r)
clump_id <- getValues(rc)    
xy <- xyFromCell(rc,1:ncell(rc))
df <- data.frame(xy, clump_id, is_clump = rc[] %in% freq(rc, useNA = 'no')[,1])
df[df$is_clump == T, ]

plot(r)
```

[image: r]

```
plot(rc)
text(df[df$is_clump == T, 1:2], labels = df[df$is_clump == T, 3])
```

[image: rc]

May not be as interesting as you could expect.

You do it all over with directions = 4

```
rc <- clump(r, directions = 4)
clump_id <- getValues(rc)    
xy <- xyFromCell(rc,1:ncell(rc))
df <- data.frame(xy, clump_id, is_clump = rc[] %in% freq(rc, useNA = 'no')[,1])
df[df$is_clump == T, ]
```

to get

[image: rc4]

and maybe clump 'centroids'

```
dfm <- ddply(df[df$is_clump == T, ], .(clump_id), summarise, xm = mean(x), ym = mean(y))
plot(rc)
text(dfm[, 2:3], labels = dfm$clump_id)
```

[image: rc4mean]

**Notes**:

There will be an error if you try to use `clump()` without first
detach **modeltools** library. modeltools is called by coin and maybe
other statistical libraries.